# Efficiently replace values in one file with values from another

Tags: jq

I have two large files, each containing millions of lines

```
**FILE 1** 

{"key1": "value1", "key2": "val1"}
{"key1": "value2", "key2": "val2"}
{"key1": "value3", "key2": "val3"}
```

```
**FILE 2**

{"f2key1": "fvalue1", "fkey2": "file2val1"}
{"f2key1": "fvalue2", "fkey2": "file2val2"}
{"f2key1": "fvalue3", "fkey2": "file2val3"}
```

The data in the lines of **FILE 1** is needed in the corresponding lines of **FILE 2** which contains large complex records with one line per record. In other words, data from line 1 of FILE 1 is needed in the first record of FILE 2 (line 1), data from line 2 of FILE 1 is needed in the second record of FILE 2 (line 2), data from line 9,999,999 of FILE 1 is needed in the record on line 9,999,999 of FILE 2.

**Expected output**

```
{"fkey1": "val1", "fkey2": "value1"}
{"fkey1": "val2", "fkey2": "value2"}
{"fkey1": "val3", "fkey2": "value3"}
```

Files are too big to be loaded into memory but restructuring to simplify processes is acceptable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, both files are formatted to contain one object per line (if not, use `jq -c` to achieve it), and you want to merge sequentially corresponding lines/objects by taking the keys from the second file, and the values from the first.

As for the sequential alignment, you can use [GNU's](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/paste) `paste` (the default delimiter `\t` doesn't interfere), then read in the objects pairwise into `jq` using `.` and `input` (without the `-n` flag), and perform the merging according to your needs. Finally, use the `-c` flag (again) to restore the one-item-per-line formatting. Unmerged demo simply using an array containing the aligned items `[., input]`:

```bash
< <(paste file1.json file2.json) jq -c '[., input]'
```

```json
[{"key1":"value1","key2":"val1"},{"fkey1":"fvalue1","fkey2":"file2val1"}]
[{"key1":"value2","key2":"val2"},{"fkey1":"fvalue2","fkey2":"file2val2"}]
[{"key1":"value3","key2":"val3"},{"fkey1":"fvalue3","fkey2":"file2val3"}]
```

As for the concrete merging, I actually couldn't grasp the logic from your example. But for the sake of demonstration, here are two approaches that you may find helpful for implementing yours. The first one just cross-assigns some values for a given set of (hard-coded) keys, which directly produces your output example:

```bash
< <(paste file1.json file2.json) jq -c 'input + {fkey1:.key2, fkey2:.key1}'
```

```json
{"fkey1":"val1","fkey2":"value1"}
{"fkey1":"val2","fkey2":"value2"}
{"fkey1":"val3","fkey2":"value3"}
```

The second one is more programmatic: It takes keys and values as they sequentially appear in the objects using `keys_unsorted` and `map`, respectively, and then uses `reduce` to iteratively bring them together (actually resulting in a swapped key-value correspondence wrt to your output example).

```bash
< <(paste file1.json file2.json) jq -c '
  map(.) as $values | input | reduce (keys_unsorted | to_entries)[]
    as {$key, $value} (.; .[$value] = $values[$key])
'
```

```json
{"fkey1":"value1","fkey2":"val1"}
{"fkey1":"value2","fkey2":"val2"}
{"fkey1":"value3","fkey2":"val3"}
```

Feel free to adapt/modify them as you see fit.

Comment: What's really going on is I need to change just a few of the values in the file2.json objects, each of which contains hundreds of values.

Comment: @KyleBanerjee As I said, you can use `paste` in combination with `jq -c '[., input]'`, and go from there applying your desired merging logic (e.g. `jq -c 'input + {fkey1: .key2, fkey2: .key1}'`). You may also explicate it, so I could try to adapt my answer to it.

Comment: This is what I needed -- combining the matching lines into an array allows me to arbitrarily assign any value from objects in file 1 to any key in file 2.  For example, to set only the f2key1 value, ```jq -c '[., input] |reduce . as $line ([]; $line |$line[1].fkey2 = $line[0].key1)' <(paste file1.json file2.json)```